# Approximation of Stochastic integral with Stieltjes integrals

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $V^n(t,\omega)$ be a sequence of continuous, adapted and bounded variation processes such that with probability 1, $V^n$ converges to $B$ uniformly on compact intervals of $[0,\infty)$ ($B$ is standard 1 dimensional Brownian motion). For $X \in L^2$ and adapted, is it true that $\int_0^T X_t dV_n$ converges to $\int_0^TX_t dB_t$ in some sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. They converge to Stratonovich integral. References : Karatzas and Shreve book and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X8390043X